# UTF-8 in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

This seems to be a common question among international developers but I haven't found a straight answer yet.
I'm getting from a feed the following string: 
"Carlos e Carlos mostram o que há de melhor na internet"

The following error is returned to the console:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 31-33: invalid data

thanks in advance,

fbr

Comment: We're unable to see the code you're using, so it's really hard to give a "straight" answer.  Also, it's hard to know where you find this "string" and what encoding it uses when you found it.  Without any code or any data, there can't be a straight answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just decode using some random encoding, even if it is UTF-8; you *must* decode using the encoding returned in the HTTP headers or an equivalent within the document (such as within the `META` element of HTML).

If the encoding isn't available or is incorrect then you should specify in [the decode operation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) what will happen on an invalid byte sequence; usually `'replace'` suffices for this.

```
>>> print u'Carlos e Carlos mostram o que há de melhor na internet'.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8', 'replace')
Carlos e Carlos mostram o que h�e melhor na internet
```